# MVC vs KVO in implementation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, model-view-controller, key-value-observing

I am a beginner in the realm of cocoa and don't understand when you should choose key value observing over the Model View Controller. My question: Can everything that is done with a MVC scheme also be implemented with KVO? Is it true as well that you could replace any KVO with a similar MVC?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are not mutually exclusive.  MVC is a general design pattern and KVO is a specific Cocoa technology which you can use in MVC applications (and other apps too).

Comment: Thanks! Another sub-question, I'm still trying to connect the dots..., I have a cocoa app that is currently using a traditional MVC scheme can I change it to use a KVO system and remove a whole lot of glue code. or is it something that you have to start with from beginning? Is it bad taste to mix the two? wow I really am bumbeling around. Any good links/ tutorials on implementing KVO?

Comment: @cwieland:  Of course you can.  Using KVO should make your MVC cleaner since you don't have to implement mechanisms in your model to let the controller know it has changed.